# VueJS,vue-form-generator Accessing $store from field callback

Tags: vue.js

I am using the vue-form-generator component. I am attempting to update a variable in the store with the response from a call back.  What I believe the relevant code is (inside the schema:fields property):

```
{
      type: 'submit',
      buttonText: 'Save Updates',
      styleClasses: ['custom-submit', 'custom-submit-primary', 'custom-submit-full'],
      disabled () {
    return this.errors.length > 0
      },
      validateBeforeSubmit: true,
      onSubmit: function (model, schema) {
    Vue.CustomSubmit('UserUpdate', model).then((response) => {
        this.$store.user = response
    })
      }
}
```

From within the Vue.CustomSubmit().then((response)) => { ... }
I don't seem to be able to access the store.

It works slightly higher in scope, such as:

```
data () {
      return {
        avatar: this.$store.getters.user.avatar,
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the `$store` directly. That's the most important part of the vuex concept. You need to use a mutation and commit it after you got the data.

Here it is described https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html